# Content type hub choice column

Tags: 2010, content-type-hub

We are working with a content type hub. There are content types on the "hub" site which are using "choice columns".
Something it is necessary to add on a special subsite a new choice attribute. Because is not necessary for every subsite, we don't add it on the "hub" content type. After publishing the hub content type again, it will delete the new choice attribute from the subsite.
Is it possible to exclude columns by publishing a hub content type?

Answer (score 1):

I think that's the default behavior of publishing content types (as a whole, I think that's the idea), I don't know a way to publish the content type excluding columns, so my recommendation is unsubscribe your special subsite from the Content Type Hub or everytime you publish your content type it'll erase your special choices and you'll have to recreate it and this is not maintanable

Answer (score 0):

The neatest way to do this is probably with content type inheritance.

Start with your base content type that you want to be used in most sites. Then create a "sub" content type which inherits from the base content type, but add in the extra choice fields that you want to use in only in some sites.

The just use your base content type on sites that only need that, and use the "sub" content type as required.